# List Children of null parent?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

With Objectify it is possible to query for the children of an object. An object can also have a null parent.

```
Parent parent;
List<Children> children = ofy().query(Children.class).ancestor(parent).list();
```

What I am wondering though is if I can query for a null Parent? So I want to know all children that have a null parent. If I pass null in the above I get an exception.

Also creating a query by the property  with a null propValue doesn't return anything.

```
  Query<T> q = ofy().query(clazz);
  q.filter(propName, propValue);
  return q.list();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If passing null in to ancestor() throws an exception from the GAE code (which I believe it does), then yes, this is a limitation of appengine.

Note that Query objects are immutable, so in your second example the filter() call has no effect.  You must reassign the q variable:

```
q = q.filter(...
```

In answer to how to get all entities with a null parent, you can do it with an inequality filter on the key:

```
Key<Parent> firstParent = Key.create(Parent.class, 1L);  // first possible parent value
List<Children> children = ofy().query(Children.class).filterKey("<", firstParent).list();
```

Comment: Since you're using ofy() I presume you are using Objectify4, which has filterKey().

Comment: Ok I have upgraded to Objectify 4. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion with a small variation. But my result list is empty...  

    Key<Parent> firstParent = Key.create(Parent.class, 1L);  
    List<Children> children = ofy().load().type(Children.class).filterKey("<", firstParent).list();